# User management system for WordPress, Node, GitLab and CLI

Tags: wordpress, git, authentication, active-directory, ldap

Currently, I have a WordPress website which takes care of my user management. Separately I have a GitLab server and single-page application (node.js).

I am about to build CLI which will allow users to a) download certain resources b) upload certain files to their account.

I would like to maintain single user repository for all services so that user didn't have to register separately + I would like to bind some logic like if user purchased something on WordPress he is allowed to download it via CLI or get access to certain git repository on GitLab.

I know that WP, Node and GitLab support Active Directory, LDAP and Kerberos however I am not sure whether this is the best solution. My personal experience with AD was mostly in Windows environment to get access to different directories.

Summary:

*Stack: services/applications*:

- WordPress website
- Node.js website
- GitLab CE server
- Custom CLI (to be built)

*Question*:

1. What would be the best solution to integrate all services (single login
   and password for all). LDAP / Kerberos or something else?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using WordPress, you need to use WP REST API.
For example, you can use [this solution](https://github.com/WP-API/wordpress-rest-api-oauth-1), as you use JS,
also see to the side with API solutions [like this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordpress-rest-api).

Answer (score 0):

Considering your question is around SSO (Single Sign-On) I would point you in the direction of OAuth.

OAuth is pretty much the industry standard and means if you want to add other services such as Google, Facebook, Twitter authorization later you will be able to support these out of the box.

> What would be the best solution to integrate all services (single login and password for all). LDAP / Kerberos or something else?

There are some providers that provide a SaaS platform for Authentication.
Check out https://auth0.com/

They have a plan that allows you to have up to 7K free users.

## WordPress

For the Wordpress piece Auth0 provide a WP plugin:
https://auth0.com/wordpress

## Node JS

You can use some of the SDK sample code:
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nodejs/01-login

## Git Lab

GitLab provides an OAuth plugin:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth_provider.html

## Custom CLI

You could potentially write your CLI in Node JS, in that case, the above sample code should be a helpful start.

If you get stuck feel free to ask and I can point you towards some other areas as well.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I just wonder how OAuth to please both - social login and CLI. Assuming that user logged in using Faceebook and wants to login using CLI, is it possible? If yes, how would that work, will CLI somehow open a browser, let user login, authorize and come back to CLI? As far as I checked this subject CLI will always require username and passord...